# Endianness and bitfields of size 1

Tags: c++, endianness

I thought that endianness is not supposed to affect structs of size at most 1 byte. But here's the code on my little endian machine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

static_assert(sizeof(uint8_t) == 1, "Wrong uint8_t size");

struct Pieces {
    uint8_t flag : 1;
    uint8_t value : 7;
};

static_assert(sizeof(Pieces) == 1, "Something went wrong with Pieces size");

int main()
{
    uint8_t value = 0b10001111;
    Pieces pieces;
    std::memcpy(&pieces, &value, 1);

    cout << bitset<8>(value) << endl;
    // 10001111
    cout << bitset<1>(pieces.flag) << bitset<7>(pieces.value) << endl;
    // 11000111
    return 0;
}
```

The result is incorrect. But if I change the order of `flag` and `value` members in `pieces` struct then the result is correct. But isn't it supposed to be as I've written? I'm expecting the first (counting from the left) bit in `value` to be the flag. It looks like endianess issue but isn't endianess supposed define the order of bytes, not bits?

Could someone explain to me what's exactly going on here?

Comment: All of @Yakk 's comments plus layout of bit fields is implementation defined you need to find the documentation for your compiler and include it in the question.

Comment: Bitfields and unions are the 2d and 3d most useless features of C++. Their representation is entirely system specific. Many compilers take bit fields of any size and expand them to 32 bits. There is no expected behavior here. Try doing a sizeof (Test).

Comment: Disregarding the code's possession of the spirit of undefined-ness, §9.6: "Bit-fields are assigned right-to-left on some machines, left-to-right on others."

Comment: @Yakk I've modified the code as you've proposed. I've removed the union, kept the inner struct only and used memcpy. But the result is unfortunately still the same.

Comment: @user3344003 sizeof both Test and the inner struct are 1.

Comment: @molbdnilo That's just... weird. Why would the standard allow bit-field reordering?

Comment: It's not reordering, it's just the lack of any specification of a particular order.

Comment: Beyond the standard not making any promises, it just isn't wrong.  This is the "natural" way anybody would expect bits to be packed, compilers don't go out of their way to make it confuzzling.  You just confused yourself by displaying the least significant bit as the most significant bit in the output.  Add a space or an endl to make it more obvious.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not sure I follow you. I expected `10001111` to be divided after first (counting from left) bit, i.e. `flag = 1, value = 0001111`. But what actually happend is that it was divided as `flag = 1, value = 1000111`, i.e. just before the last bit. Wouldn't you call my approach to be natural? It is consistent with the order of the bit fields.

Comment: I believe most people would interpret the lsb to be the "first" bit, as it is the lowest power of 2 (thus the lowest "index").

Comment: @user3344003 unions are quite useful actually, for sum types to be precise.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth That's very interesting. I've never thought about it that way. This also seems to be consistent with the struct's layout without bit-fields. People learn every day.

Comment: Thank you guys for all that clarification. Someone pls post an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @freakish I think you should update the question: remove the code with the `union`, change the title. The main question seems to be about the bitfield.

Comment: @freak try self answering!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let me gather all the info from comments.

It seems that the order of bit fields is not specified in the standard and thus is implementation dependent. The relevant part of the standard is (thanks to @molbdnilo):

> §9.6: "Bit-fields are assigned right-to-left on some machines, left-to-right on others."

Also let me note other comments. It seems that the order of bit fields is simply reversed in memory. This seems to be consistent with the order of normal fields as well and is probably consistent with endianness (I would appreciate if someone can check it on a big-endian machine).

I guess that's what "right-to-left on some machines" and "left-to-right on others" means. However this is my interpretation and as stated earlier we should not depend on it.